Как поменять кодировку в SQL Shell?
Установил PostgreSQL по обучающим курсам, вроде всё сделал по инструкции, ничего лишнего не нажимал, однако при открытии консоли SQL Shell и при вводе команды текст нечитаемый:

Пробовал через regedit заходить в \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor и создать файл autorun со значением chcp 1252.
Пробовал ввести в cmd консоли:
psql -d -U
/c chcp 1252

Но выдаёт ошибку.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

@aleksandrbarakin позволю себе заметить, что приложенный к вопросу автором скриншот - это не код, не данные и не текст ошибок.

"Но выдаёт ошибку." — уточните, какую ошибку

В cmd до вызова psql меняем кодировку chcp 65001, или chcp 1251
